# efficient way of moving req.body properties to model object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking for a shortcut to some of the tedious boilerplate code I've been doing when creating a crud REST api.  I'm using express and posting an object which I wish to save.

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
  var profile = new Profile();

  //this is the tedious code I want to shortcut

  profile.name = req.body.name;
  profile.age = req.body.age;
  ... and another 20 properties ...

  //end tedious code

  profile.save()
});
```

Is there an easy way to just apply all req.body properties to the profile object?  I will be writing the same crud code for sever different models and the properties will be changing frequently during development.

Comment: I suppose I can just ...for (var i in req.body) if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) { .. but wondering if there are any other random fluff properties added to req.body that I should filter out

Comment: How about moving the tedious code to a function so that you only have to do it once? e.g. profile = GetProfileFromBody(req.body);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a *for-in* loop, assuming your `new Profile()` will generate a good schema to put values on, which will avoid req.body to mess you up.

```
for (var key in profile) {
  if (profile.hasOwnProperty(key) && req.body.hasOwnProperty(key))
    profile[key] = req.body[key];
}
```

More precisely, you should have a parse/stringify function for each of your module for this case. So that you can simply call:

```
var profile = Profile.parse(req.body);
```

In fact, if you are playing with non-IE browsers or in node.js/rhino, and your req.body is *clean*, you can just do it like:

```
var profile = req.body;
profile.__proto__ = Profile.prototype;
```

And you're done.

Comment: I think you might want to check `profile .hasOwnProperty(key)` as well / instead

Answer (score 0):

Can do something like this:

```
for(key in req.body) {
  profile[key] = req.body[key];
}
```

Comment: While it doesn't scope sensibly, you should probably have a `var` in there.

Comment: does req.body add any fluff or system properties that I have to filter out.  When does one need to check for req.body.hasOwnProperty(key)?

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over all keys is probably a bad idea. Better would be:

```
['name', 'age', ...].forEach(function(key) {
    profile[key] = req.body[key];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use spread operator (...).

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
  var profile = new Profile({...req.body});
  profile.save()
});
```